# PHP How to Delete Multiple Records using Checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a little problem regarding with deleting multiple records in my table. I used checkbox in order to delete them but it doesn't work. I don't know what would be the exact CODE for it.

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php   
    echo "<form action='#'>
        <fieldset>
            <input type='text' name='search' value='' id='searchtalents' placeholder='Search Keywords..' size='40'/>
        </fieldset> 
    </form>";

    echo "<form name='tmsform' method='POST' action=''>";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM talentinfo WHERE 1 LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ({$sql}) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No rows found";
        exit;
    }

    echo"<div id='talentinfo'><table id='mr_database' name='myform' style='border:1px solid #fff;' cellspacing=0 cellpading='2' class='pretty'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Mr Tracking Number</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Contact Number</th>
                <th>School</th>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Year Graduated</th>
                <th>Position Considered</th>
                <th>Referred Location</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>";

    $counter = 40000;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $filled = (($counter % 2) == 1) ? "style='background-color:#BCD9E1;'" : "" ;
    $id = $row['talents_id'];

    echo "<tbody><tr {$filled} class='tmsdel'>";        
    echo "<td><a href ='#' rel='#edit_talents{$counter}'><center><img src='img/edit.gif' width='25' height='21' title='Edit'></center></a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href ='#'  id=".$row['talents_id'].'&idelete=talents'." class='delete'><center><img src='img/delete.png' width='25' height='21' title='Delete'></center></a></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='check".$row['talents_id']."' value='".$row['talents_id'].'&idelete=talents'."'/></td>";          
    echo "<td><a href='#' rel='#tracing_number{$counter}' style='text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; color:#444;'>" . $row ['mr_tracking_number'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['middlename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['contact_number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['school'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['course'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['year_graduated'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['position_considered'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['referred_location'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['unit'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr></tbody>";
?>
```

And here is my Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    });     

    $("#delete-all").click(function(){
        $("#mr_database").remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: "modules/delete-all.php",
            type: "get",
            async: false,
            data: "check"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is this your query- ? $sql = "SELECT * FROM talentinfo WHERE 1 LIMIT 10"; ????? although this is going to work but i guess you wan tto save some condtn in WHERE

Comment: Rory McCrossan what kind of condition sir?

Comment: swapnesh like what condition sir?..I'm still getting to learn on PHP..thank you

Comment: first of all it would be g8 if u use only Swapnesh/@swapnesh :)  and next if ur fetching all results then its ok if u use only this -> SELECT * FROM talentinfo

Comment: @swapnesh ok sir...i got it..what is the difference if I remove the WHERE 1 in my query? Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Please follow steps:

1. First you need to apply any class name to your all checkboxes.
2. Call function on button click for delete then

   ```
     var allVals = '';

     $("#delete-all").click(function(){

      $('.checkboxclass :checked').each(function() {
        allVals = allVals + $(this).val() + ',';
      });
   }
   ```
3. Then you need to pass `allVals` variables in `ajax` and post to .php file

   Like:  data: `'ids=' + allVals`  in $.ajax
4. In last you can get this variable in php file and do delete process on it.

   Like:   `$ids = explode(',', $_REQUEST['ids');`  and use ids in mysql query

   Hope this helps you.

Comment: var allVal = 'checkboxes';
$("#delete-all").click(function(){
$('.checkboxes :checked').each(function(){
 allVal = allVal + $(this).val() + ',';
});
Check = confirm("Do you really want to delete ALL DATA ? (Hint: there is no undo)");
 if (Check == true) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "modules/delete-all.php",
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        data: "talents_id" + allVal
    });
 }
});

Comment: You can put this code which i change in your above code                       $("#delete-all").click(function(){var allVal = '';   $('.checkboxes :checked').each(function(){ 
allVal = allVal + $(this).val() + ','; 
}); 
Check = confirm("Do you really want to delete ALL DATA ? (Hint: there is no undo)"); 
  if (Check == true) { 
   $.ajax({ 
    url: "modules/delete-all.php", 
    type: "post", 
    async: false, 
    data: "talents_id=" + allVal
   }); 
  } 
 });                                                           ("checkboxes" is a classs name which you need to assign in all checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Rather simple answer since what i am seeing here is a script to view the table and delete the html in the browser but not the data on the server.

You need to write the modules/delete-all.php script mentioned here:
    url: "modules/delete-all.php"

which should contain the " delete * FROM talentinfo " SQL Query.

This however will seamlessly delete all table contents. So you might want to do a prompt:

```
$("#delete-all").click(function(){

Check = confirm("Do you really want to delete ALL DATA ? (Hint: there is no undo)");
if (Check == true) {
 $("#mr_database").remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: "modules/delete-all.php",
        type: "get",
        async: false,
        data: "check"
    });

}
});
```

The delete_all.php should delete all, so just do:

```
<?php   

$sql = "delete * FROM talentinfo ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ({$sql}) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
} else {
    print "ok";
}
?>
```

Comment: include("../includes/initialize.php");

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;

switch($id){
 
 case "talents_id"
  
 $sql = "DELETE from talentinfo WHERE talents_id= $id";
  
 break;

}                                                                         on what part will I put the Check = confirm("Do you really want to delete ALL DATA ? (Hint: there is no undo)");
if (Check == true) {
 // do the deleting here
}

Comment: I changed my answer to indicate the position of the confirm().

Comment: concerning your delete_all.php: you do not pass any parameters in the **$.ajax** call so you wont get any **$_GET['id']** in the delete_all.php. You also call the delete-all.php from the delete all button. You do not need a parameter to delete all.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer...my little problem is that it doesn't really delete the table. When I refresh the site it was there again.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer...my little problem is that it doesn't really delete the table. When I refresh the site it was there again.

Comment: Hi, sorry but was gone for the weekend. Did you look whether the delete_all.php gets called by the browser at all?